# Smooth Shading Average Across Faces

Tags: modeling

I created a simple object and I have creased all of the edges apart from 4 with a crease.

I have auto smooth on at 30

[image]

Why do all of the vertex normals point in the same direction. I thought that the ones that were not creased would average out with the faces they are connected with?

This is what it looks like with a sub-d of 2 and auto smooth

[image]

Comment: auto smooth simply makes the faces look smoother, so you can make a low-poly model look smooth.  Crease is so that you can keep certain parts of your model sharp, such as corners and edges of your model, while still having other parts smooth as a result of the subdivision surface modifier

Comment: mark sharp is what helps you use to keep some edges sharp while still using the auto smooth.  If you give the object an edge split modifier, it will keep the marked sharp edges, well, sharp :)

Comment: This is a good question and I would like to upvote, but could you please edit it to make the title more descriptive?

Comment: Title edited. Thank you for the replies. The question really is looking at the direction of the normals as shown on the verticies they all look the same. I understood that the direction was affected by he adjacent faces when it was auto smoothed. I expected to see the normals facing a different way. Instead the normals are the same but the edge is not creased. thanks again

Comment: you could try re-settting normals, ctrl-N

Comment: Recalculating the normals outside (shift+n) does not change anything - thanks